# How to show webform submitted data in drupal7

Tags: drupal

i want to display the webform submitted data in drupal 7 and that survey only admin can see.After the submission i want to show the submitted data to admin in table format and also wants to download that data in excel Sheet format. What approach i should follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call this function which is called after the data is inserted in the webform.
This hook will provide you the node id and and the submission id. Using this submission id you can access all the data which you have inserted and can perform your task inside it.

```
function  hook_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission) {
   //do your task

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Install this module http://drupal.org/project/webform_report it will be displayed in table format and also you can customize the report & also It will create separate content type.

Below is the screen shot for webform report, you can also view, edit & delete from report itself.

[image]

hope your requirement will match this!!!

Comment: Thanks Bala, Could u please help me out how to create sticky table header in drupal 7, i have created template file for that webform.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.. I thought the native table generator pretty functional.  It includes a download button.

login as admin, then go to: Content --> Webforms Tab --> Your webform --> Submissions (or better = TABLES ! ) to see what the users have submitted.  At the far right side of the TABLE display is a download button.  With this selection you get EVERYTHING downloaded in a convenient XL sheet.

I know I'm a late comer to this party, and perhaps this enhancement is a late addition to the software.  Solution offered here to aid others in the future.